# How to specify schema for the folder structure when reading parquet file into a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have to read parquet files that are stored in the following folder structure
**/yyyy/mm/dd/** (eg: 2021/01/31)

If I read the files like this, it works:

```
unPartitionedDF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("abfss://xxx@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/Address/*/*/*/*.parquet")
```

Unfortunately, the folder structure is not stored in the typical partitioned format **/yyyy=2021/mm=01/dd=31/** and I don't have the luxury of converting it to that format.

I was wondering if there is a way I can provide Spark a hint as to the folder structure so that it would make "2021/01/31" available as yyyy, mm, dd in my dataframe.

I have another set of files, which are stored in the /yyyy=aaaa/mm=bb/dd=cc format and the following code works:

```
partitionedDF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("abfss://xxx@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/Address/")
```

**Things I have tried**

I have specified the schema, but it just returned nulls

```
customSchema = StructType([
  StructField("yyyy",LongType(),True),
  StructField("mm",LongType(),True),
  StructField("dd",LongType(),True),
  StructField("id",LongType(),True),
  StructField("a",LongType(),True),
  StructField("b",LongType(),True),
  StructField("c",TimestampType(),True)])

partitionDF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").schema(customSchema).parquet("abfss://xxx@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/Address/")
display(partitionDF)
```

the above returns no data!. If I change the path to: "abfss://xxx@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/Address/*/*/*/*.parquet", then I get data, but yyyy,mm,dd columns are empty.

Another option would be to load the folder path as a column, but I cant seem to find a way to do that.

TIA

Databricks N00B!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you load the data without the partitioned folders as you mentioned

```
unPartitionedDF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("abfss://xxx@abc.dfs.core.windows.net/Address/*/*/*/*.parquet")
```

Then add a column with the `input_file_name` function value in:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
unPartitionedDF = unPartitionedDF.withColumn('file_path', F.input_file_name())
```

Then you could split the values of the new `file_path` column into three separate columns.

```
df = unPartitionedDF.withColumn('year',  F.split(df['file_path'], '/').getItem(3)) \
                    .withColumn('month', F.split(df['file_path'], '/').getItem(4)) \
                    .withColumn('day',   F.split(df['file_path'], '/').getItem(5))
```

The input value of `getItem` function is based on the exact folder structure you have.
I hope it could resolve your proble.

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Would you suggest using this method, or should I invest the time in moving the files to a proper partitioned folder structure with /key=value/ format?

Comment: In total it's recommended to have the partition name in the folder structure, it helps you to use the available tools easier (i.e. AWS Athena, and much more). In your case, as you know the structure and if you know it will not change in the future you could keep it as it is. But if it change in the future (i.e. adding a new root folder) you need to update the input for the `getItem` function.